SAP Configuration in GUI
We are currently developing the bot to automate the manual process across various applications. However, we are encountering an issue with the SAP configuration related to the scripting settings, which is critical for the bot to function smoothly.
Specifically, we need the following configuration:

Enable Scripting under Accessibility & Scripting > Scripting
Disable the following options:

Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI
Notify when a script opens a connection



The issue arises when, after a certain period, the scripting settings revert to being enabled. This necessitates manual intervention to reset the settings, which in turn disrupts the bot’s performance and its seamless operation.
We have tried the Registry Values (https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/dfad9ecd79db404eba46fdd709013a78/8a3fc9a6b01b4536b910452b5c300245.html) but we're able to handle only "Scripting". Not "Notify when a script attaches to SAP GUI" and "Notify when a script opens a connection".
Please advise if there is a way to control this behaviour through configuration to ensure the settings remain consistent? Any guidance or support on automating or locking these settings would be immensely helpful.
Thank you in advance for your assistance, and I look forward to your response.

There's no reason that the SAP GUI settings are reverted "automatically". Check any script in your system which could revert (e.g. an SAP GUI Installation Server). No reason too that changing the registry values don't change the settings (unless authorization errors or script error).

SAP settings are sometimes controlled by Group Policy objects as well. Below are the troubleshooting steps/solutions you can try:

Ask your Org. admin for a specialized GPO for SAP installed machines where the Robot runs.
If there is no GPO make sure to edit the registry during the automation
If the options 1 and 2 are not possible, then using ABAP will also work.
Automate SAP using SAP BAPI (System user is enough you wont even need a dialog user with the right permissions/access level)
Check the local SAP config files while setting up SAP (In the config files the default might be to enable them when SAP restarts or periodical reset)

let me know if none of the above work. post the screenshots of your config/registry etc and we can see what else can be done.
